# Parse de feed no Python

Tags: python, feed

Acesso um feed cujo layout é dessa forma:

```html
<horoscope>
 <date>20170627</date>
 <listItem>
  <item>
  <signTitle begin="21/03" end="19/04">Áries</signTitle>
  <content>
   BNononononononononononon
  </content>
  <linktexto>
   <![CDATA[ 
    <a href='' target='blank'></a> ]]>
  </linktexto>
  <textosaida>
   <![CDATA[ 
    ]]>
  </textosaida>
  <linksaida>
   <![CDATA[ 
    <a href='' target='blank'></a> ]]>
  </linksaida>
  </item>
 </listItem>
</horoscope>
```

Ao fazer o parse usando a biblioteca feedparser, quero extrair no valor da tag , no caso "Áries", mas ao invés disso recebo o seguinte output:

{'begin': '21/03', 'end': '19/04'}

Que são os atributos "begin" e "end" da tag. Mas o valor interno realmente não vem. Meu código segue abaixo:

```
import feedparser
d = feedparser.parse(caminho_do_xml)
for post in d.entries:
  print(post.signtitle)
```

Como eu posso acessar o conteúdo da tag, ao invés de somente os atributos? Obrigado.

Comment: Você precisa de apenas Áries ou de todos os textos dos elementos?

Answer (score 1):

Que tal:

```
import feedparser

rssfeed = """
<horoscope>
    <date>20170627</date>
    <listItem>
        <item>
        <signTitle begin="21/03" end="19/04">Aries</signTitle>
        <content>
            BNononononononononononon
        </content>
        <linktexto>
            <![CDATA[
             <a href='' target='blank'></a> ]]>
        </linktexto>
        <textosaida>
            <![CDATA[
             ]]>
        </textosaida>
        <linksaida>
            <![CDATA[
             <a href='' target='blank'></a> ]]>
        </linksaida>
        </item>
    </listItem>
</horoscope>"""

d = feedparser.parse(rssfeed)

for e in d.entries:
    print e['content'][0].value
```

Saída:

```
BNononononononononononon
```

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi bem o que precisa, você não necessitará de bibliotecas de terceiros (como acho que a `feedparser` é). O Python possui nativamente uma biblioteca para trabalhar com XML. Veja:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree

# Elemento raiz do XML:
root = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse("feed.xml").getroot()

# Itera sobre todos os elementos listItem:
for listItem in root.iter("listItem"):

    # Itera sobre todos os elementos item:
    for item in listItem.iter("item"):

        # Busca pelo elemento signTitle:
        signTitle = item.find("signTitle")

        # Imprime seu conteúdo:
        print(signTitle.text)
```

> Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/JDwI/0).